# How can I split the background of an image and a color in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to split the background of an image and a color.
This is the current set up on how it looks but every time I resize the background for mobile it just pushes the image over to make it look stretched.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/2000);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: right;
  background-size: 65vw 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: teal;
  max-width: 100%;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  height: 60px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 12px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Cherry Bomb One', cursive;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.logo {
  font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.sign-up {
  height: 46px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.log-in {
  height: 46px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.login {
  color: white;
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  height: 70vh;
  margin: 0 0 20px 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

p {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

input {
  width: 350px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 45px;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.button {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #4C4646;
}

.sign-in-link {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.sign-link {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: normal;
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  button {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Permanent+Marker&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Food To You</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="logo">Food To You</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <div class="log-in">
          <li><a class="login" href="#">Log in</a></li>
        </div>
        <div class="sign-up">
          <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="search">
    <p class="search-header">Order food to your door</p>
    <form action="">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter delivery address">
      <button type="button">Deliver now</button>
      <button type="button" class="button">Find Food</button>
      <p class="sign-in-link"><a class="sign-link" href="#">Sign In</a> for your recent adress</p>
    </form>
  </div>

</html>
```

https://imseanfaulkner.github.io/Food-To-You/

Comment: note that your HTML Markup is invalid and that you miss a closing tag (body).

Comment: The background gets squished because you have its height and width set up depending on the viewport size. One way to avoid it would be to set the background width to auto so it keeps the aspect ratio, and then set its position to 35vw (100vw - 65vw) to keep your original layout. So it would look like this:

    `body { background-position: 35vw center; background-size: auto 100vh; }`

But you'll see that only a small portion of the image is visible on mobile due to the vertical screen orientation.

So the real question here is: how do you want it to look on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

You can [stack background images](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp), and you can [use a CSS gradient as a background image](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.php). So just place a gradient in front of your photo, a gradient which is opaque on the left to make your solid color, then transparent on the right so that the photo is visible below.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(0,128,128,1) 35%, rgb(0,128,128,0) 35%), url(https://picsum.photos/2000);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

The great thing about this solution is that you can, if you wish, adjust the transparency of the gradient to either allow some of your image to bleed through the solid color on the left, or to tint the image on the right, or both.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(0,128,128,0.9) 35%, rgb(0,128,128,0.3) 35%), url(https://picsum.photos/2000);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

The [CSS Gradient](https://cssgradient.io/) site is a great tool for creating, editing and generally experimenting with gradients.